# Perl - From Database to data structure

Tags: sql, perl, dbi, perl-data-structures

I'm querying a table in a database with SQL like this:

```
Select col1, col2 from table_name
```

For reference, col2 will be an integer value, and col1 will be the name of an element. E.G.

```
FOO, 3
BAR, 10
```

I want a data structure where the values can be addressed like `vars->{valueofcol1}` should return the value of `col2`.

So

```
$vars->FOO
```

would return 3

Basically I don't know how to return the SQL results into a data structure I can address like this.

Comment: Did you check the manual of the module which you use to access a database?

Comment: @leeduhem yes but I don't understand it, hence my question

Comment: @mpapec that data structure looks too deep for my idea.

Comment: Actually you'll have to do `$vars->{FOO}` because it's a hash key. You **cannot** do `$vars->FOO` because `$vars` is not blessed into a class, so Perl cannot call the sub `FOO` from that classes package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch reach row and build that hashref yourself.

```
my $vars; # declare the variable for the hash ref outside the loop
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{select col1, col2 from table_name});
$sth->execute;
while ( my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ) { # fetch row by row
  $vars->{ $res->{col1} } = $res->{col2}; # build up data structure
}

print $vars->{FOO};

__END__
3
```

You may want to [read up on DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI), especially [how to fetch stuff](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_arrayref).

Comment: Thank you, I will test this code and get back to you.